# Set file system as modules database using MarkLogic REST API

Tags: rest, configuration, marklogic, marklogic-8

I want to use MarkLogic 8's REST API to create an app server which uses the file system as the module database as shown in this image:

[image: Modules database using file system]

I've tried the following variations, with the results described below each command:

```
curl -v -X POST --anyauth -u admin:admin --header "Content-Type:application/json" \
-d '{"rest-api": { "name": "MyAppServer", "port": "8012", "database": "MyDB", "modules-database": 0 } }' \
http://127.0.0.1:8002/v1/rest-apis
```

**Creates a database named "0" (without the quotes)**

```
curl -v -X POST --anyauth -u admin:admin --header "Content-Type:application/json" \
-d '{"rest-api": { "name": "MyAppServer", "port": "8012", "database": "MyDB", "modules-database": "(file system) } }' \
http://127.0.0.1:8002/v1/rest-apis
```

**Error**

> ADMIN-INVALIDCONFIG: (err:FOER0000) Invalid configuration:  '(file system)' is not a valid database-name

If it's not possible to set the modules database using the REST API, is it possible to load files into the modules database using the REST API? I've only found documentation on inserting documents into the data database.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think inserting documents in the modules database works fine, assuming you set the proper permissions & such.

Comment: adding documents to the modules database is no different to any other database (use the document API for posting documents or MLCP, etc). However, you must make sure that you include the proper permissions (read and execute) for the user using the application.

Comment: If you're amenable to using Gradle as a build automation tool, https://github.com/rjrudin/ml-gradle will automate tasks like this that utilize the MarkLogic Management REST API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuring the modules database to the file system is not supported for REST API appservers.

The REST API needs to be able to write and read documents in the modules database.

A REST client can read and write documents in the modules database for a REST API appserver by treating it as a content database.  Either:

- Create a different REST API appserver that has the modules database as the content database. (One could think of this as a "meta" REST API appserver.)
- Specify the database parameter when connecting to a REST API appserver.

Just be careful not to write files in the directories managed by the REST API for a modules database:

```
/GROUP_NAME/
/marklogic.rest.*/
/ext/
```

Hoping that helps,

Comment: I chose the "meta" app approach as I don't want the global REST API enabled on my app - thanks!