# Difference between selecting FileSystem and selecting Modules database in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

How different is selecting those options in Marklogic Admin Database? How does it affect one over the other? and are there any performance issues while selecting one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the modules are loaded and cached, there isn't a difference between a modules database and the filesystem with regards to performance and functionality.

If you have a cluster with multiple MarkLogic servers, it can be easier to deploy and manage modules in a Modules database. You load once and the cluster knows where to find and read the modules, rather than having to put those modules on the filesystem on every one of the nodes that would need to read the modules.

If you have a single server, deploying and updating files on the filesystem isn't as difficult. Sometimes, for quick prototyping and editing files on the filesystem can be faster and more convenient. However, with tools such as ml-gradle and the [`mlWatch`](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Common-tasks#automatically-load-newmodified-modules) task, loading modules in a modules database as you edit not really that big of a deal.

[If you plan to use REST extensions, then would need a modules database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42145627/14419) so that the configurations can be installed in that database.

Generally, you should use a modules database especially for production deployments. Then you can also take advantage of the database features such as backups, transactions etc.

Comment: Thanks mads Hansen. I have a Simple question: what code is saved in modules database ? I know xquery/Java but what is it do. What is it for ? Thanks

Comment: The XQuery or JavaScript modules are the code that you use to talk to the database and perform work. Whether searching, inserting, modifying, or deleting documents, or transforming the data being returned to the client. You can expose and execute that code in a number of ways, through HTTP or XCC appservers.

Comment: So does that mean I have an application with code on file system or modules in ML mean the code is used to return the data from marklogic database to the application for the requests made by end user (front end).did I understand it right ?

Comment: The client could be a front end user (browser), or it could be a middle tier application server in a 3-tier architecture. But whoever makes the request, would be executing the code in a module which can read/write/search database content.

Comment: Thank you Mads Hansen!