# Any performance difference between loading ML Module (Xquery / Javascript) from physical disk localation and loading from ML Module DB inside ML?

Tags: performance, marklogic

By default, ML HTTP server will use the **Module DB** inside ML.
(It seems all ML training materials refer to that type of configuration.)
Any changes in the XQuery programs will need to upload into the Module DB first. That could be accomplished by using **mlLoadModules** or **mlReloadModules** ml-gradle commands.
CI/CD does not access the ML cluster directly. Everything is via ml-gradle from a machine dedicated from code deployment to different ML enviroments like dev/uat/prod etc.

However it is also possible to configure the ML app server to use the XQuery program from **physical disk location** like below screenshot.
[image: Load Module From Disk]
With that configuration, it is not required to reload the programs into ML Module DB.
The changes in the program have to be in the ML server itself. CI/CD will need to access to the ML cluster directly. One advantage of this way is that developer will easily see whether the changes in the program have been indeed deployed, as all changes are sitting as physical  readable text files in the disk.

**Questions:**

1. Which way is better? Why?
2. Any ML query perforemance difference between these two different approaches?
3. For the physical file approach, does it mean that CI/CD will need to deploy the program changes to all the ML hosts in the ML cluster? (I guess it is not a concern if HTTP server refers XQuery programs from Module DB inside ML. ML cluster will auto sync the code among different hosts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's recommended to deploy modules to a database rather than the filesystem.

This makes deployment more simple and easy, as you only have to load the module once into the modules database, rather than putting the file on every single host. If you use the filesystem, then you need to put those files on every host in the cluster.

With a modules database, if you were to add nodes to the cluster, you don't have to also deploy the modules. You can then also take advantage of High Availability, backup and restore, and all the other features of a database.

Once a module is read, it is loaded into caches, so the performance impact should be negligible.

[If you plan to use REST extensions, then you would need a modules database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145101/set-file-system-as-modules-database-using-marklogic-rest-api/42145627#42145627) so that the configurations can be installed in that database.

Some might look to use filesystem for simple development on a single node, in which changes saved to the filesystem are made available without re-deploying. However, you could use something like the [ml-gradle `mlWatch` task](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Watching-for-module-changes) to auto-deploy modules as they are modified on the filesystem and achieve effectively the same thing using a modules database.

Comment: Mads, is the ml-gradle mlWatch / mlLoadModule / mlReloadModule stable?
Or can that guarantee to work?

I remember I saw some cases that the changes in the program could not load to the Module DB somehow. In the end, people have to run mlDeploy to build everything, which is something too heavy for me to run in production.