# How to send XQuery Code to eval at one particular MarkLogic App server that configured to use local file as its Module DB?

Tags: visual-studio-code, xquery, marklogic

[MarkLogic Visual Studio Code Extension](https://github.com/marklogic-community/mlxprs) provides a way to dynamically send the Xquery code to different MarkLogic enviroments by changing mlxps:setting in its header comment block.
[image]

However, it does not work if the Xquery will need to refer to other Xquery library files stored on the local drive, as there is no option to set which ML Http server that the Xquery should be evaluated at.

[image]

In contrast, if we need to run the same Xquery from QConsole,
[image]

Here is the screenshot if I try send it to port 8300 which is the used for that http server form visual studio code.
[image]

**Any solution for that?** Does it mean this mlxprs could only work for Module in Module DB?
(This is the same problem for sending Xquery form ml-gradle, as one could not specify which App server the XQuery will be sent to.)

Comment: Are you sure that the REST Client API has been installed/enabled on that HTTP appserver? https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/service#id_15309 If not, then it won't know how to process a /v1/eval request.

Comment: I follow the above guide to recreate a new REST clint API on the same server. 
After that, I modify the xquery header  mlxpres setting to use that port. 
Now I am getting a different error message.

https://i.imgur.com/xVLuyFt.png

Comment: From the error message, it seems that it could not find the config-var.xqy file. However I am sure the file indeed on that windows disk. I am not sure whether the mixed windows and unix filepath seperator caused the problem. 

I compared the newly created REST API server with the existing one. They are indentical except the name. The next question is why the response is different? Error 404 vs Error 500

Comment: A more simple test might be helpful. Try eval with code that only does `xdmp:invoke("/test.xqy")` with that test module simply returning a string "Hello World", and see if that works. It may be that the module you are attempting to invoke has an issue, or other code in that eval? When I attempt to break things locally (wrong path for root or module URI) I don't see the same error response.

Comment: Also verify that what you have defined as the root directory really is the top level root path for all of your modules and you don't have any of the imported module attempting to look for something above/outside of that base directory structure? Also verify what the permissions are for your modules 
(might try testing with a privileged user account and see if you get different results): https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/handling-xdmp-modnotfound-and-xdmp-noprogram-errors

Comment: I could duplicate the problem on my local latest ML 10.0-7 on my win 10.

Comment: I could duplicate the problem on my local latest ML 10.0-7 on my win 10.
[Hello.xqy](https://i.imgur.com/RVWsdsf.png)

If I remove that 'xdmp:invoke("config-var.xqy")', i could get proper response.

Here is the screenshot of my local REST API HTTP server configuration setting.
[REST API http server](https://i.imgur.com/yeKn0Ll.png)

Comment: There is more stacktrace msg from ML 10.0.7
_"stackTrace": "XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: (err:XQST0059) Module D:\\Temp\\ML-XQuery-Modules\\/config-var.xqy not found\nin /config-var.xqy,\nin xdmp:invoke(\"/config-var.xqy\") [1.0-ml]\nat 13:20,\nin xdmp:eval(\"(: mlxprs:settings&#13;&#10;{&#13;&#10;  &quot;host&quot;: &quot...\", (), <options xmlns=\"xdmp:eval\"><database>4397174533146017526</database>...</options>) [1.0-ml]\nin /eval, at 1:330 [1.0-ml]\n  $options = <options xmlns=\"xdmp:eval\"><database>4397174533146017526</database>...</options>"_

Comment: Here is the content of that config-var.xqy
https://i.imgur.com/YfosNLn.png

Comment: And you are sure that the appserver has `(file system)` configured as the Modules database? The only time I see the root path displayed with double backslashes is when I have a module database selected (not filesystem) and have the root path configured as `D:\Temp\ML-XQuery-Modules\` and in the error message it shows as ` SVC-FILOPN: xdmp:invoke("/config-var.xqy") -- File open error: open 'D:\\Temp\\ML-XQuery-Modules\\/config-var.xqy': No such file or directory` but note that it has SVC-FILOPN instead of the XDMP-MODNOTFOUND that you show.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/G0E0hxp.png

Comment: It returns 0. that means it is indeed configured as file system for Modules-Database.

If I run the same Xquery from QConsole, it could open that xquery and get the content correctly.
https://i.imgur.com/jvP5bY6.png

Comment: I noticed the difference between 404 error and 500 error might be caused by url rewriter setting in that http server. 

https://i.imgur.com/PToG2P4.png

**/MarkLogic/rest-api/url-rewriter.xqy** is the one created by default when I create with REST api http server via curl. However where is the url-rewriter.xqy. 
That may explain why running the query from QConsole works but from VSC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be an issue that in order to eval code against the appserver, it needs to use the [`/v1/eval`](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/eval) endpoint, and that appserver needs to be configured as a REST-API server.

However, [configuring the modules database to use the filesystem is not supported for REST API appservers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42145627/14419).

The path of least resistance would be to use a modules database and deploy your modules, rather than trying to use the filesystem, but it is an inconvenient limitation.